# How to swap lat long values of geom type cloumn in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, latitude-longitude, swap, geom

`update place_tab_25062020 SET ST_Y(location) = ST_X(location), ST_X(location) = ST_Y(location) WHERE ST_Y(location)<35 and ST_Y(location)>0;`

I have location as geom i need to swap its lat long values

Answer (score 0):

İ solved it like that

update place_tab set location = (SELECT ST_MakePoint( ST_Y(location),ST_X(location)))
WHERE ST_Y(location)<35 and ST_Y(location)>0;